# What CHKDSK exactly logging and reporting, 'flashing' messages on prompt?

Tags: chkdsk

Seems nobody interested in giving answer to be exact about this 'issue' on last post.

So i just re-writing up new thread with question as more simply.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjeKb.png)

This is the screen just before exiting chkdsk. There were bad sectors on the disk. In that case some files, I heard, could be deleted when chkdsk is executed with /r switch, so I turned it off in haste. As you see, chkdsk didn't leave any messages that it deleted or modifed something. Still could there be any files already deleted? When I checked it out after the terminaton no found.xxx folder or chk file was found.

It is said that there could be losses in the data recorded on the sectors marked as bad in the recovery process using /r switch. What I'd like to know is if there could be any possibility that when the job occurred it proceeded without leaving any job history on the prompt screen.

Comment: `Seems nobody interested in giving answer to be exact about this 'issue' on last post` - I don't understand that statement. You got an answer on that question, which you accepted. Maybe the problem is that it isn't the answer you wanted... but it is the answer you got and the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told in another answer, files are not deleted during `/r` operation. It only goes through the data in the disk, and if some part of a file is in a bad sector area, then another sector is allocated to replace that bad sector. That sector is empty, which means that the file is still corrupted on that position.

So, there is no difference if chkdsk did something with the `/r` switch or not, the files are still corrupted and cannot be recovered unless handed out to a professional recovery company.

I don't know for sure, but I think that chkdsk will show messages about the reallocation of bad sectors when going through the disk.

Comment: Thank you for your reply last time and now. according to screenshot, chkdsk was checking 869 clusters and did not find any errors yet (judging by prompt, any error messages aren't leaved on prompt), so i assume chkdsk did not touch any data/sectors yet, and i canceled before something can happen with data/sectors by chkdsk. how do you think about this conclusion? i tried to understand your answers with my poor English, but thought it is better to change question like this. may i get your help again?

Comment: The fact is that the data blocks that are in bad sectors are lost. That fact does not change if you run chkdsk with `/r` and let it finish or if you don't run it. You cannot get them from the hard drive by yourself. A professional data recovery company might be able to get the data. I suggest you copy everything from the drive to a working drive and then check if you need further recovery.

Comment: Unfortunately log was not created in this time because of abort chkdsk by myself. and i am aware of that your point the data on bad sectors are already damaged. for make sure, after abort chkdsk i moved all data to new disk by TeraCopy and only some folder was not able to copy so i deleted, replaced it from back up data. let's point at screenshot again...

Comment: ...chkdsk did not record any error messages on prompt. so i guessing chkdsk didn't touch any data/sectors yet = i canceled before something can happen with data/sectors by chkdsk. this is my point. do you think this is wrong conclusion?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I assume that chkdsk shows messages when it reallocates working sectors to bad sectors.

Comment: That is the thing make me crazy, actually Microsoft Support Engineer in community clearly told me i didn't lose 'any' data in 'this' case because chkdsk didn't do anything, as prompt "record" showing. but only one person in another forum told me 'chkdsk "flashing" message like -recovering sector xxx-' and i should aware of it, he still no answer for correction after what he said. that is why i asking same question again in other place. i wanna quit think of chkdsk issue anymore, so it is only thing should be clear.